# AMP- include icons in amp pages

Tags: amp-html

I am trying to display my custom icons which is published in npm, currently i am loading from node_modules which is working fine in non-amp versions but i am not sure about how to include this in AMP version, anyone tried this way, many thanks in advance

something like this `/node_modules/icons/fonts/`

Comment: you can use `amp-img` with `src=target-icon` or (if SVG) you can embed in the page using an SVG class and identified items.

Answer (score 0):

here how i achieve to load icons, added to the scss file

```
@font-face {
    font-family: your-iconfont;
    src: url(../../node_modules/your-icons/fonts/font.eot) format("embedded-opentype"), url(../../node_modules/your-icons/fonts/font.woff) format("woff"), url(../../node_modules/your-icons/fonts/font.ttf) format("truetype"), url(../../node_modules/your-icons/fonts/fonts.svg) format("svg");
    font-style: normal
}
```